# Best and quickest way to get exchange mailboxes count per database

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I am in the process of automating active directory accounts creation for new employees using Powershell script; and one of the tasks is to create a new user mailbox and place it in a database with the lowest number of mailboxes; so in order to get total number of mailboxes per database; one option is to connect to exchange and mailboxes count as follow

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Group-Object -Property:Database | Select-Object Name, Count | Sort-Object Name | Format-Table
```

but its a little bit slow, i though that i could get a quicker way by utilizing the `HomeMDB` attribute of the active directory accounts and created the following function

```
function Get-MailboxPerDatabase(){     
    # get all AD account with excluding health and system mailboxes  
    $MBs = Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -notlike "HealthMailbox*"} -Properties mail,homemdb | where {$_.mail -match "@" -and $_.samaccountname -notlike "SM_*"} | Group-Object Homemdb
    $Mailscount = foreach ($MB in $MBs){
        [string]$DB = $MB.Name
        [pscustomobject]@{
        Database = $DB.Substring(3,$DB.IndexOf(',CN')-3)
        Count = $MB.count
        }
    }
    $Mailscount | sort Count 
}
```

and This gives me the following result

```
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex"
At line:4 char:9
        [pscustomobject]@{
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
 

Database   Count
--------   -----
MGR1       330
DB3       330
DB2       330
MGR2       331
DB1       331
DB4       332
```

my questiones here:

1. why i am not able to get index of `,` (`comma`) and as a workaround i get the index of `,CN` and return back 3 steps.
2. is this a valid way to get the number of mailboxes or should i stick the exchange normal method.

**Edit**: I managed now to get ride of this error after modifying the

```
    $MBs = Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -notlike "HealthMailbox*"} -Properties mail,homemdb | where {$_.mail -match "@" -and $_.samaccountname -notlike "SM_*" -and $_.homemdb -match 'CN'} | Group-Object Homemdb
```

Answer (score 0):

for everyone who is following this post or looking for a quick way to get number of mailboxes per database;

This is how the final function looks like:

```
function Get-MailboxPerDatabase(){     
    # get all AD account with excluding health and system mailboxes  
    $MBs = Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -notlike "HealthMailbox*"} -Properties mail,homemdb | where {$_.mail -match "@" -and $_.samaccountname -notlike "SM_*" -and $_.homemdb -match 'CN'} | Group-Object Homemdb
    $Mailscount = foreach ($MB in $MBs){
        [string]$DB = $MB.Name
        [pscustomobject]@{
        Database = $DB.Substring(3,$DB.IndexOf(',')-3)
        Count = $MB.count
        }
    }
    $Mailscount | sort Count 
}
```

the execution time of this function took only **2.3390401** seconds on domain controller

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> (Measure-Command -Expression {Get-MailboxPerDatabase}).TotalSeconds

2.3390401
```

while getting the same info directly from exchange server using the `Get-Mailbox` command took **59.96** Seconds

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>(Measure-Command -Expression { Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Group-Object -Property:Database | Select-Object Name, Count | Sort-Object Name | FT}).TotalSeconds

59.9602879
```

*According to the results:*

using the `Get-MailboxPerDatabase` function on Domain Controller

```
Database   Count
--------   -----
MGR1      330
DB3       330
DB2       330
MGR2      331
DB1       331
DB4       332
```

using the `Get-Mailbox` command on exchange server

```
Database   Count
--------   -----
MGR1      330
DB3       330
DB2       330
MGR2      331
DB1       331
DB4       333
```

I noticed that the result is different on database `DB4`, count from function is `332` but count from exchange is `333`; After examining the results; i found that exchange shows in the result `DiscoverySearchMailbox` which is not returned by my function `Get-MailboxPerDatabase` and this is OK for me, i didn't want to include it.

According to the question about indexof `comma`, i found that there is no problem about it, but the problem was from the `substring` method the syntax is
`Substring( StartIndex [, length] )` so if i needed to get the name of the database i need to subtract `3` from the result like `Database = $DB.Substring(3,$DB.IndexOf(',')-3)`